# Will any copy of Arkham City activate on steam?

Tags: pc, steam, batman-arkham-city

With the holidays coming up and games likely to go on sale, I'm interested in picking up a copy of the PC version of Arkham City.

I've had good experiences with Steam as a way to keep my (very few) games organized and was wondering: If I purchase any retail version of Arkham City, will it activate on Steam? Or do I need to purchase directly from Steam to make sure that happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Arkham City is not on [the Retail CD Keys list](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=7480-WUSF-3601) for games that can be [activated on Steam](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=5414-TFBN-1352).

Comment: Actually Batman: Arkham City is the 15th bullet point on that list. Perhaps it was edited in the mean time?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this post](http://steamcommunity.com/games/200260/announcements/detail/1909817119598626547) from Erik Miller it should be possible since GFWL is being shutdown and WB are replacing it with Steam in Arkham City and Asylum.

I haven't been able to convert my retail key but some comments on the same post indicate that they provided proof to purchase to WB Games support and were given Steam keys. Comments on [this](http://www.rockpapershotgun.com/2013/10/19/batmans-ditched-gfwl-but-say-goodbye-to-your-saves/) RockPaperShotgun thread indicated that they had purchased the game originally from GamersGate and have been issued with new Steam keys.

Answer (score 0):

The retail version of batman will not work on steam, but it will still require GFWL.  This is cobbled together from google cache of steam forums and other various sites, so I might be wrong.

You should purchase from steam if you already own lego batman or arkham asylum as you'll receive a nice 20% discount.

Answer (score 0):

I had a boxed disc version of City from Best Buy that wouldn't activate on Steam at first but it now has. It may have been some technical problem on Warner Brothers' part.

I moved my saved game with the hex-editor hack from the Steam Forums.